# peek-char in scheme

Tags: scheme, racket

Just need to know the basics of peeking in scheme. I tried looking at the racket site for help but it didn't have much on it. Or maybe I was looking in the wrong section. Anyways, the point of this is the following.

if I have `(#\x #\b #\o #\x #\space #\3 #\6 #\0)`

I want to be able to identify x as a char and then continue peeking until space is reached and redefine this as a word. Then do the same for 360.

Any tips? Please and thank you! : )

Here is what my code looks like in case it helps

```
(define (work x) 
(cond
((null? x)(write '$$))
(char-numeric? (car x))
(write 'Num)
(toke (cdr x)))
((char-alphabetic? (car x))
(write 'ID)
(work (cdr x)))
(else (write "other")))
```

The problem with this is that it would give me IDIDIDID for "xbox" (which makes sense cause of the code) but I want to make it output just ID once for the whole word xbox

Oscar, I know you helped me out with this but my lack of knowledge in scheme didn't allow me to get far. Sorry for the repost.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the section on peek-char in the manual: [http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Byte_and_String_Input.html#(def.*((quote.*~23~25kernel)._peek-char))](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Byte_and_String_Input.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._peek-char%29%29)

An example (where I use a string as input port in order for the
example to work without an extra data file):

```
> (define a-string "Foo bar")
> (define in (open-input-string a-string))
> (peek-char in)
#\F
> (peek-char in)
#\F
> (read-char in)
#\F
> (peek-char in)
#\o
> (peek-char in)
#\o
> (read-char in)
#\o
> (read-char in)
#\o
> (peek-char in)
#\space
```

Comment: THANKS! That's all I needed to know. I can take it from here : )